# Any way to remove the voltage impulse of DC motors, both ways?

Tags: circuit-design, dc-motor, circuit-protection

I'm attempting to make a circuit for controlling the direction of a DC motor by comparing two photo resistors, so far i managed to make the logic of swapping polarities, amplify the output and connect it to a motor, however when the polarities swap i noticed an insanely high voltage spike on the motor.
I tried to simply add a diode before realizing it only works for one flow direction. any way to remove this spike both ways?
[image: Circuit Schematic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each transistor needs a diode, for commutation. The diodes are over the emittor and collector. The direction is contrary to the emittor "arrow".

Comment: works perfectly, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use MOSFETs in the H-bridge. The body diodes function as commutation diodes.

The circuit below also gets rid of the comparator IC :) The MOSFETs should be small surface-mount parts rated at least 2A continuous drain current. D1-D3 are silicon diodes. D4 and D5 are yellow or green LEDs. They indicate motor direction as well as reduce shoot-through current in the H-bridge.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgqGbf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>